# unable to import js file in visual studio code

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vue-component, vue-native

as you can see I tried to import the js from `src/services`

I tried the following path but none of them working.

```
./services/member.service

/@services/member.service

member.service
```

Previously I used `/@store/member.service` for my others Vue project but somehow it is not working in vue native

[image]

**my member.service.js**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `@;services/member.service` ?

Comment: @s4k1b with semicolon?

Comment: @s4k1b tested with `@;services/member.service` and `@services/member.service` and `@/services/member.service` but none of them working

Comment: You want `../services/member.service`. The `.` in `./` refers to the current directory which for your `member.module.js` file is `src/store` so you were asking for `src/store/src/services/member.service`

Comment: try specifying `.js` at the end of the file and see if it works. eg `@/services/member.service.js`

Comment: That being said, if `@/constants/constants` works, then `@/services/member.service` should too

Comment: @Phil whats the `../` means?

Comment: Parent directory

Comment: @Phil testes, it works, please add your answer below so that i can mark it as answer